# Removing Youtube app search history

Tags: youtube, search-history

I've got a problem with the Youtube app's search history. It contains only two entries and none of the searches done before or after are shown. The app doesn't save the new entries.

I tried removing both cache and data for the app, but that didn't help. The 2 entries are restored soon after I log in again.

I'd like to remove all entries, or make new entries show up again - I'm happy with either solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete individual searches**

You can delete individual searches from your search history when you’re signed in with your account by following these steps:

1.Tap the search icon

2.Tap and hold a suggested search result with the history icon  next to it.

3.Tap Remove on the pop-up asking if you want to remove this entry from your search history.

**Clear your entire search history**

To clear search history for your account, go to Menu > Settings > Privacy and tap Clear search history.

Source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57711?hl=en

Comment: That worked just fine for removing the entries. New entries are still not saved, but that's not a big deal.